# How to make CSS justify-content:space-evenly fallback to space-between on Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm building a webpage and running test against different browsers, one of the designs involves a flexbox and space-evenly, I know this is not widely supported yet, so as a fallback I'm using space-between like this:

```
.some_element {
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
justify-content:space-evenly;
}
```

Above code works correctly on: Firefox, Chrome, IE11, Edge but fails on Safari.

Safari does understand and recognize the `space-evenly` property but does nothing with it, in other words the result is the same like: `justify-content:initial;`

Officially Safari doesn't support `-webkit-justify-content` so I thought I will be cleaver and try the fallback as this:

```
.some_element {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content:space-evenly;
    -moz-justify-content:space-evenly;
    }
```

But again Safari does understand it and it renders it same like `initial`. Same happens on iOS, which makes my website design fall apart.

Aesthetically the space-evenly looks better so I will really like to take advantage of it on browsers which support this, so I'm not to keen on dropping it because of Apple. On the other hand, Apple users are a significant part of the visitors so I cannot ignore the problem and leave the page render with the `initial` look.

Comment: Just tried `@supports` in [this test](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/OOBPBq?editors=0100) and sure Safari is OK with the test but won't apply the value... Thanks Safari :(

Comment: Yeap I had / have the same feeling that I will need to "punish" all users because of Apple... :(

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`@supports` is of no help, see my comment above (hey Apple, can you remind me what was the point of this feature? Sigh) but you can have the same layout with `:pseudo`s and `space-between`.
The only constraint is you can't use pseudos on the flex container for anything else.

➡️ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/wPYaGv?editors=0100)**

➡️ Relevant code:

```
.evenly-like {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
  }
}
```

With 5 items, there are 6 "spaces" equally wide with `space-evenly` and 4 with `space-between` (and half + 4 + half with `space-around`).
By creating 2 :pseudos on the flex container and given they're considered flex items by teh power of Flexbox, with `space-between` there are now 5+2 = 7 items thus 6 equally wide "spaces", problem solved.

➡️ Complete snippet:

```css
/* /!\ Pasted from compiled Scss in Codepen with Autoprefixer. Your browserslist is probably not as complete as that one :) */

.parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:     flex;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.parent.evenly {
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
     -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.parent.around {
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
}
.parent.between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
     -ms-flex-pack: justify;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.parent.evenly-like {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
     -ms-flex-pack: justify;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.parent.evenly-like:before,
.parent.evenly-like:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: slateblue;
  outline: 1px dotted darkblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>space-evenly</h1>
<div class="parent evenly">
  <div class="item">1 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">2 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">3 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">4 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">5 lorem</div>
</div>

<h1>Mimicking space-evenly with space-between: and :pseudos</h1>
<div class="parent evenly-like">
  <div class="item">1 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">2 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">3 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">4 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">5 lorem</div>
</div>

<hr>

<h1><i>space-around</i></h1>
<div class="parent around">
  <div class="item">1 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">2 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">3 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">4 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">5 lorem</div>
</div>

<h1><i>space-between</i></h1>
<div class="parent between">
  <div class="item">1 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">2 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">3 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">4 lorem</div>
  <div class="item">5 lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice trick (workaround) somehow I did not thought about it... In my case this solves the problem because I do not have any other pseudo on the container. Thanks a lot! However the mighty lord of Apple should still get it's finger out of his notch and solve the real problem of Safari :)

Comment: Very nice! Edge has the same problem, including the @supports shame, and of course your workaround works there as well.

Comment: Nice trick, although it doesn't work in case you are using flex wrap.

Comment: Correct @EnriqueOriol - for flex-wrap we have to set it to `justify-around` then figure out the spacing between the elements when it is `justify-evenly`. Say it's 10px. Then add padding-left and padding-right that is half that, so 5px.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*for ie*/
justify-content: space-around;
/*for moz & chrome*/
-webkit-justify-content: space-evenly !important;
```

[justify-content property in ie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/jj127304(v=vs.94))

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain your answer so other can understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

flex-grow should also solve your problem:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  .child {
    flex: 1
  }
}
```

Thus, all children share the container space evenly as they have the same flex-grow value.